# NSMutableDictionary returns empty NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

At mouseDown and mouseDragged:

```
locll = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
NSValue *locationValuell = [NSValue valueWithPoint:locll];
[vertices addObject:locationValuell];
```

at mouseUp

```
NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex++];
[aDict setObject:vertices forKey:index];
NSArray *allKeys = [aDict allKeys];
NSLog(@"dict count: %ld", [allKeys count]);
NSString *index1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex];
NSMutableArray *a = [aDict objectForKey:index1];
NSLog(@"a count:%li", [a count]);
```

at initWithCoder

```
int aIndex = 0;
```

dict count returns how many objects are stored in dictionary. And it works. But later when I try to get array back from dictionary, I check how much objects array has ([a count]) and it returns 0. So i guess NSMutableDictionary empties my NSMutableArray, or I am taking it back in wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aIndex++];
```

you increment `aIndex` **after** using it (post-increment). So if `index` is "0" then `index1` will be "1". Therefore

```
NSMutableArray *a = [aDict objectForKey:index1];
```

returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing your aIndex by 1 after using it for saving vertices in aDict. And you access this key after it(aIndex) is increased by 1. Naturally your aDict doesn't contain any array for that key.

Answer (score 0):

Just try out this:

```
       NSMutableArray *a=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[aDict objectForKey:index1], nil];
```

It should be work.